# having trouble in installing composer on for wamp

Tags: php, composer-php, wamp

From last 3 days i am trying to install composer on my local system WAMP (windows 7). When i install composer it through an error :

> `The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
>   failed to open stream: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
>   forbidden by its access permissions.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why you dont try composer installer? Composer-Setup.exe

Comment: Sigh. When will MS-Windows _finally_ get a working and usable software management system as it is common and proven on other operating systems?

Comment: I run it => Composer-Setup.exe. After selecting a path for installing composer and click on install, it throw error.

Comment: Maybe it's just a temporary DNS problem. Try to access https://getcomposer.org/versions in the browser.

Comment: getcomposer.org/versions gives me response

Comment: {
    "stable": [{"path": "/download/1.4.2/composer.phar", "version": "1.4.2", "min-php": 50300}],
    "preview": [{"path": "/download/1.4.2/composer.phar", "version": "1.4.2", "min-php": 50300}],
    "snapshot": [{"path": "/composer.phar", "version": "17b7387c374e202680c0da16a5f82fa2b9be17d6", "min-php": 50300}]
}

Comment: Have you checked that `php_openssl` is activated ?

Comment: Where to check it?

Comment: In `\wamp\php\php{version}\php.ini` This is the php ini file used when you are running PHP CLI scripts, so dont sonfuse it with the other one

Comment: there is no comment before =>  extension=php_openssl.dll.                               It means its activated.

Comment: Please help me out to solve this issue. Because of it, i am unable to install laravel.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?